# Why the php 'if statement' does not give expected result?

Tags: php, ajax

I am designing a php application using AJAX and PHP.
But the if statement in my php file behaves unexpectedly.
The request method is 'POST';
Ajax code  is

```
        function fetchData(){
            var recipename = document.getElementById("recipe").value;
            var calorie = false;
            createRequestObject();
            //window.alert(calorie);
            var url = "reciepinfo.php"; 
            xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            window.alert(calorie);
            xmlHttp.send("recipe="+recipename+"&calorie="+calorie);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlHttp.readyState===4 && xmlHttp.status===200){                       
                    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;                                          
                }
            }
        }
```

And php code is:

```
  <?php
 $_SESSION['flag']=false;
if($_SESSION['flag']==false){
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['flag']=true;
}
$recipename = $_REQUEST['recipe'];
$calorie = $_REQUEST['calorie'];  
 echo $calorie;
 $calorietemp = 0;
 //echo $recipename;
 $database = "nutrition";
 $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',$database);
 $query = "select * from recipestb where name='$recipename'";
 //$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
 //$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result);;
 if($link){
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    //$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   //$names = "";
    if(is_object($obj)){
            echo "<i/>";
            echo "<font size='5'>";
            echo "Recipe name: ".$obj->name;
            echo '<br/>';
            echo "Carbohydrates : ".$obj->carbs." grams";
            echo '<br/>';
            echo "Proteins: ".$obj->protein." grams";
            echo '<br/>';
            echo "Fat: ".$obj->fat." grams";
            echo '<br/>';
            echo "Calories: ".$obj->calorie." cal";
            $calorietemp = $obj->calorie;
            echo '<br/>';    

    }else{
        echo "non object";
    }

 }else{
     echo "Connection failed";
 }
if($calorie==true){
     echo $calorie;
     $_SESSION['caloriecount'] = $_SESSION['caloriecount'] + $calorietemp;           
     echo "Total calorie in diet :".$_SESSION['caloriecount'];          
}
```

My session handling is weird i accept, but neglecting that, even the variable calorie is explicitly set to false, the if block executes.The echo $calorie statement also executes and it displays $calorie as false.
And i am not getting what is going wrong exactly.
Almost irritated with this.
Can anybody help?

**EDIT1:**
The php code is fine...
Ajax code has some problem...
When i set the $calorie to false in php code.. 
It behaved properly..

Comment: I suspect this might have to do with variable types. Are you sure `$calorie` is a boolean? If it has the string value `"false"`, it would evaluate to boolean `true` in the if-statement, but still come out as `false` when you echo.

Comment: @Abhishek Malakar  nah still not working..

Comment: @Anders see in the fetchData() ... i have set it to false..

Comment: Not sure the type information is preserved through the AJAX call to the PHP. Try running `$calorie = (strtolower($calorie) === 'true'? true: false;);` somewhere before the if statement. Not sure about this, though. Just guessing. But it is worth a try.

Comment: @Anders thank you for your kind interest in my issue.. It is solved ..See the edit 2.

Comment: Glad that you solved the issue! Instead of editing the question, you should post your solution to the problem as an answer, and accept it (or some other answer that helped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner i was unaware that the java-script variable with value false is passed as a string "false" to a server side script like PHP.

If we use a boolval(), in PHP this issue can be resolved.
[PHP boolval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php)

I set the $calorie in my java-script to 0 or 1 as per my need.
When i wanted the false value to be sent to PHP script ,i set $calorie in java-script to 0 and the boolval() in corresponding PHP script evaluated it as false.
So the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the session handling aside, the $calorie problem ...
You pass the data via AJAX as **strings**.

```
$calorie = 'false';
var_dump((true == $calorie));
```

You will get always `bool(true)`. Using your AJAX example above, try this snippet instead (and use POST instead of REQUEST):

```
$calorie = ('true' == $_POST['calorie']);
var_dump($calorie);
// produces `bool(false)`
```

Comment: I know ... revised my posting - your problem is $_POST variable handling and types. false and 'false' have different meaning.

Comment: That might be the issue let me check.. wait

Comment: I used $calorie = boolval($_POST['calorie']); And passed '1' and '0' values as $calorie using java-script as per requirement. And problem solved! Sorry for the trouble

Comment: boolval is good idea, yet available PHP > 5.5. hint: Vote up anyone who helped :)

Comment: Haven't tried your solution.. Will try n let you know.. Thank you!

Comment: really thanks a lot for your help but i am working on a project that has to be submitted in few hours. i will ask you to wait. I did not try your trick as i came to solution of the problem on my own.  Well I have already up voted your answer as the string thing u told was really helpful ,trust me. I will let you know by Indian standard time 9 p.m. Please don't feel offended. Have a wonderful day!